# GTFS realtime feed example script

Tags: java, visual-studio, gtfs

I was able to successfully parse through BART's GTFS realtime Service Alerts and TripsUpdate feed. I also looked at the official protocol buffer for Java tutorial page and was able to compile and run the tutorial. 
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial

The next part for me is figuring out how to create a Realtime feed maybe preferably Service Alerts first for my GTFS static data. From what I understand a GTFS realtime feed is like sending protocol buffer data that is serialized to a webpage and then writing a script that takes in the web link that refers to the page and deserialized the data using HTTP GET. I was thinking of using Visual Studio and ASP.NET core to do this. Is there an example project I can refer too and/or am I even on the right track in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [awesome-transit list of gtfs-realtime stuff](https://github.com/luqmaan/awesome-transit#gtfs-realtime).  A lot of libraries within the OneBusAway project are probably your best bet for seeing code in action that deals with gtfs-realtime.  For example, maybe you can look at [onebusaway-gtfs-realtime-exporter](https://github.com/OneBusAway/onebusaway-gtfs-realtime-exporter/wiki).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the Onebusaway project. I learned something from the Alerts demo page that I should create a new and seperate component that creates a realtime data alert stream in JSON. https://github.com/OneBusAway/onebusaway-gtfs-realtime-alerts-producer-demo/wiki